# Definition of distance d of the QECC $T(S)$

Tags: error-correction

**Definition of distance $d$:**

$d$ of $T(S)$ is the weight of the smallest Pauli operator $N$ in $N(S)$ \ $S$.
$S$ is the stabilizer, $T(S)$ is the corresponding QECC, and $N(S)$ are all errors commute with elements in S.

**I am confused about this definition, especially about the "weight".**

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help clarify it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The weight of an error in QEC is the number of qubits, on which the error acts non-trivially. For example, the error $X\otimes Y\otimes Id$ has weight two. The weight is important, because usually we know that a code can correct errors up to some weight.

Comment: That is a really concise and great answer! Thanks!!